# Does a System.Drawing to TikZ solution exist?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Not sure if this belongs to here or to a .NET forum.

Does anybody know of an implementation to reuse .NET coded drawings with TikZ? Or any ideas, how to do that? I just want to know, if it would be easy or doesn't worth the work.

To give an example: Drawings in C# are done like this:

```
static Pen black = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0), 1);
```

gives us the line. The color and a thickness `1`.

```
SmoothingMode saveMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

some sample properties which can be ignored for the beginning.

```
int aVariable = 20;
    Point startPos = new Point(0, 142);
    Point curvePos = new Point(43, 134);
    Point endPos = new Point(72, 116);
    for (int y = 0; y <= aVariable; y++)
    {
        g.DrawCurve(black, new Point[] { startPos, curvePos, endPos });
        startPos.Y = startPos.Y + 4;
        curvePos.Y = curvePos.Y + 4;
        endPos.Y = endPos.Y + 4;
    }
```

or

```
Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(80, 132, 178, 223);
Color color2 = Color.FromArgb(132, 178, 223);
g.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(124, 19), new Point(124, 25), color1, color2), new Rectangle(124, 19, 29, 6));
```

demonstrate some drawings.

I think, there are a lot of parallels to TikZ as everything is defined by coordinates, lines, curves or rectangles. So any idea about how to reuse this code is welcome.

Comment: Any vector description of graphics will come down to describing line widths, move/draw operations, _etc._ As such, you could make a similar request for any other vector language. My feeling is this question is likely either a straight 'no' (I don't think there is a converter) or 'too broad' (writing one is a major operation).

Comment: If there is a .NET library that exports the final drawing in (some vector graphics format that can be converted to) SVG, you can use Inkscape to convert that to TikZ.

Comment: @JosephWright You are absolutely right. I just wanted to listen around, if someone has done some work here.

Comment: @marczellm I just got the same idea one second ago. Found this here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge Maybe that's allready a solution. Anybody has used that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Collecting the comments to write an answer:*

No, there is no converter around. Or at least not a known one.

Easiest solution would be, to export the drawings to SVG with a library like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge

The SVG can be treated within Inkscape. Inkscape has an export function to TikZ which is still in work but already gives nice results.